# What is better: caching through HttpContext.Current.Cache or just a static?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ihttpmodule

Last night I wrote up my first `IHttpModule` to do some request processing. I'm using a regular expression to inspect the raw url. The `IHttpModule` will be called on every request, so it seems reasonable to do some sort of caching of the regular expression object to prevent creation of it on every request.

Now my question... what is better: use the `HttpContext.Current.Cache` to store the instantiated object or to use a `private static Regex` in my module?

I'm looking forward to the reasons why. Just to clarify: the regex will never change and thus always be the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the regex isn't going to change (and it usually isn't), then:

```
private static readonly Regex pattern = new Regex("...", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

is the fastest and most efficient in every way

Comment: But is there not a risk of `pattern` being null if process recycles?

Comment: @Aliostad - no.  since it's a static property of the class, it will be recreated when the class is first referenced.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends. Built in cache can offer you automatic expiration control while static objects can't. Also, if you want to change the cache mechanism (let's say you have to distribute your applicaiton) you can with built in cache. Static objects are just it, static.

Comment: while true, for a simple regex such concerns are usually overkill

Comment: @Marc - I would go even further and say that it's a code smell (Speculative Generality?). You've created a dependency that doesn't need to exist, i.e., what should be a static property is now data in an unrelated class.

Answer (score 3):

I would as a rule use a static field and save caching for when you need more control of the lifetime of the object. Here are two reasons I can think of right ahead:

- There is always some overhead involved in caching the object and retrieving it from the cache, at least there will be boxing/unboxing
- You will have to access the item by a cache key rather than directly in code, this makes the application somewhat bulkier and more difficult to understand

You should ask yourself if you *need* the functionality you get by caching the object, i.e. lifetime.